# How to pass a member function in for each loop?

Tags: c++, class, foreach

I'm trying to use `std::for_each()` instead of a normal `for` loop as a practice, but I can't pass a member function to `for_each()`.

Here is the code:

```
class Class
{
    public :
        void func (int a)
        {
            cout << a * 3 << " ";
        }
}ob1;

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = { 1, 5, 2, 4, 3 };
    cout << "Multiple of 3 of elements are : ";
    for_each(arr, arr + 5, ob1);
}
```

It works only if this member function is `void operator() (int a)`. I don't know why any other member function cannot be passed into `for_each()`!

Comment: You might pass lambda: `for_each(arr, arr + 5, [&](int e) {ob1.foo(e);});`...

Comment: Good question - there are so many possibilities - see Remy's answer for at least 4.

Comment: @JBRWilkinson are you thinking there are more than 4 ways?

Comment: ok, thanks, I understand how to obtain it by lambda, but how to do it by `bind()` finction ?

Comment: @MohamedSaad there is an example of `std::bind()` in my answer

Comment: Ok thanks, it's in answers , I will check it @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not passing any class method to `for_each()`, you are passing an object, which only works when the object implements `operator()`.

To let `for_each()` call your `Class::func()` method, you would need to either:

- implement `operator()` in your class:

  ```
  class Class
  {
  public:
      void func (int a)
      {
          std::cout << a * 3 << " ";
      }

      void operator()(int a)
      {
          func(a);
      }
  }ob1;

  std::for_each(arr, arr + 5, ob1);
  ```
- use a separate delegate that implements `operator()` to call into your class.

  - you can define a custom functor (pre-C++11):

    ```
    struct functor
    {
        Class &obj;

        functor(Class &c) : obj(c) {}

        void operator()(int a)
        {
            obj.func(a);
        }
    };

    std::for_each(arr, arr + 5, functor(ob1));
    ```
  - or use [`std::bind()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) (C++11 and later):

    ```
    #include <functional>

    auto func = std::bind(&Class::func, &obj1, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::for_each(arr, arr + 5, func);
    ```
  - or use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (C++11 and later):

    ```
    auto func = [&](int a){ obj1.func(a); };
    std::for_each(arr, arr + 5, func);
    ```

Answer (score 2):

The `for_each` function has several overloads which can be seen [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each).

> `C++` - `std::for_each` - `Algorithm` library
>
> Defined in header ***`algorithm`***
>
> ```
> template< class InputIt, class UnaryFunction >
> UnaryFunction for_each( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f ); 
> // (1) (until C++20)  
>
> template< class InputIt, class UnaryFunction >
> constexpr UnaryFunction for_each( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f ); 
> // (1) (since C++20)  
>
> template< class ExecutionPolicy, class ForwardIt, class UnaryFunction2 >
> void for_each( ExecutionPolicy&& policy, ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryFunction2 f ); 
> // (2)  (since C++17)
> ```
>
> - 1) Applies the given function object f to the result of dereferencing every iterator in the range `[first, last)`, in order.
> - 2) Applies the given function object f to the result of dereferencing every iterator in the range `[first, last)` (not necessarily in order). The algorithm is executed according to policy. This overload does not participate in overload resolution unless `std::is_execution_policy_v``<``std::decay_t``<``ExecutionPolicy``>``>` is true.
>
> For both overloads, if the `iterator type` is `mutable`, `f` may modify the `elements` of the `range` through the `dereferenced iterator`. If `f` returns a result, the result is ignored.
>
> Unlike the rest of the algorithms, `for_each` is not allowed to make copies of the `elements` in the sequence even if they are `trivially copyable`.

---

> **Parameters**
>
> **first**, **last** -
>
> - the range to apply the function to
>
> **policy** -
>
> - the execution policy to use. See execution policy for details.
>
> **f** -
>
> - function object, to be applied to the result of dereferencing every iterator in the range `[first, last)`
> - The signature of the function should be equivalent to the following:
> - `void fun(const Type &a);`
> - The signature does not need to have `const &`.
> - The type `Type` must be such that an object of type `InputIt` can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to `Type`.
>
> **Type requirements**
>
> - **`InputIt`** must meet the requirements of [LegacyInputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator).
> - **`ForwardIt`** must meet the requirements of [LegacyForwardIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator).
> - **`UnaryFunction`** must meet the requirements of [MoveConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveConstructible). Does not have to be [CopyConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible)
> - **`UnaryFunction2`** must meet the requirements of [CopyConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible).

---

This tells you all of the requirements that are needed for your `predicate`, `function object` or `functor` that is needed to satisfy the condition(s) needed for `for_each`'s last parameter. If you wish to avoid having all of your class's or custom data structures defining the `operator()` then you could write a generic functor that will implement the `operator()` for your class(es), or you could use a `lambda`. You can refer to [Remy Lebeau's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau) answer for implementation details.